# Does the StereoBM class in opencv do rectification of the input images or frames?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing

I am using the SteroBM class for a stereo vision as part of my project. I am taking the input frames from 2 Web cams and running the Stereo block matching computation on the input frames gray scale frames without rectification. The output I am getting is far from the ground truth(very patchy). I want to know, is it because I am not doing rectification on input frames. Moreover, the base line I have chosen to keep at 20cm. I am using opencv-3.2.0 version c++.

The code I am running is given below.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include </home/eswar/softwares/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/contrib_world/include/opencv2/contrib_world.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
 //initialize and allocate memory to load the video stream from camera 
 VideoCapture camera0(0);
 VideoCapture camera1(1);

 if( !camera0.isOpened() ) return 1;
 if( !camera1.isOpened() ) return 1;
 Mat frame0,frame1;
 Mat frame0gray,frame1gray;
 Mat dispbm,dispsgbm;
 Mat dispnorm_bm,dispnorm_sgbm;
 Mat falseColorsMap, sfalseColorsMap;
 int ndisparities = 16*5;   /**< Range of disparity */
 int SADWindowSize = 21; /**< Size of the block window. Must be odd */
 Ptr<StereoBM> sbm = StereoBM::create( ndisparities, SADWindowSize );
 Ptr<StereoSGBM> sgbm = StereoSGBM::create(0,    //int minDisparity
                                    96,     //int numDisparities
                                    5,      //int SADWindowSize
                                    600,    //int P1 = 0
                                    2400,   //int P2 = 0
                                    10,     //int disp12MaxDiff = 0
                                    16,     //int preFilterCap = 0
                                    2,      //int uniquenessRatio = 0
                                    20,    //int speckleWindowSize = 0
                                    30,     //int speckleRange = 0
                                    true);  //bool fullDP = false
//-- Check its extreme values
double minVal; double maxVal;
while(true) 
{
   //grab and retrieve each frames of the video sequentially 
   camera0 >> frame0;
   camera1 >> frame1;

   imshow("Video0", frame0);
   imshow("Video1", frame1);
   cvtColor(frame0,frame0gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
   cvtColor(frame1,frame1gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);

   sbm->compute( frame0gray, frame1gray, dispbm );
   minMaxLoc( dispbm, &minVal, &maxVal );
   dispbm.convertTo( dispnorm_bm, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));

   sgbm->compute(frame0gray, frame1gray, dispsgbm);
   minMaxLoc( dispsgbm, &minVal, &maxVal );
   dispsgbm.convertTo( dispnorm_sgbm, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));

   imshow( "BM", dispnorm_bm);
   imshow( "SGBM",dispnorm_sgbm);

   //wait for 40 milliseconds
   int c = cvWaitKey(40);
   //exit the loop if user press "Esc" key  (ASCII value of "Esc" is 27) 
   if(27 == char(c)) break;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Although in the code you see block matching also being used, please ignore because its giving even worse output. I find that the SGBM output is closer to the ground truth and therefore I've decided to improve on it. However if any help about how the block matching results can be improved. It would great and I'd certainly appreciate that.

Th output image depth image for SGBM technique looks like.
[image: Depth map using SGBM method]

Comment: Yes you need to obtain the cameras calibration data and then use it to rectify your images. That is because the `cv::Stereo(SG)BM` assumes that epipolar lines are perfectly horizontal and will not find any good match if they are not. Also these algorithms are very sensitive to their parameters so try to change them.

Comment: I downloaded the data from the middlebury dataset site and they are unrectified images. Now this means that I don't have the camera details. How do I rectify the images? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are different datasets on this website. For the multiview's *temple* and *dino* datasets you will have to read the calibration data from a text file. Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp) to see which functions are used to rectify images (`cv::stereoRectify` then `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap` then `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap`). I also recommend you Kaehler & Bradski's Learning OpenCV 3 book.

Comment: Also to debug the rectification step the easiest thing is probably to plot some epilines before and after rectification to see if they get corrected. I remember having seen online some example code to do that.

Comment: I actually have this example code. But being an amateur at Opencv coding I wasn't able to figure out about how to give the parameters from the command line. Can you give a sample command to run so that I can deduce what's happening and run some experiments for a better understanding.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have time to do that. I did not mean that you have to understand this sample entirely, just follow the execution flow near the functions I mentioned. Also read these function documentations. SO is for more specific questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated above I tried rectification of the frames. The code is below.

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include </home/eswar/softwares/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules/contrib_world  /include/opencv2/contrib_world.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d/nonfree.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

int main()
{
//initialize and allocate memory to load the video stream from camera 
VideoCapture camera0(0);
VideoCapture camera1(1);
int count=0;
Mat loRes, hiRes;
if( !camera0.isOpened() ) return 1;
if( !camera1.isOpened() ) return 1;
camera0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 400);
camera0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 400); 
camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 400);
camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 400);
Mat frame0,frame1;
Mat frame0gray,frame1gray;
Mat dispbm,dispsgbm,disparity,disparity1;
Mat dispnorm_bm,dispnorm_sgbm;
Mat falseColorsMap, sfalseColorsMap,falsemap;
Mat img_matches;
Mat H1,H2;

int ndisparities = 96;   /**< Range of disparity */
int SADWindowSize = 7;
Ptr<StereoBM> sbm = StereoBM::create( ndisparities, SADWindowSize );

Ptr<StereoSGBM> sgbm = StereoSGBM::create(-3,    //int minDisparity
                                    96,     //int numDisparities
                                    7,      //int SADWindowSize
                                    60,    //int P1 = 0
                                    2400,   //int P2 = 0
                                    90,     //int disp12MaxDiff = 0
                                    16,     //int preFilterCap = 0
                                    1,      //int uniquenessRatio = 0
                                    60,    //int speckleWindowSize = 0
                                    20,     //int speckleRange = 0
                                    true);  //bool fullDP = false


 //-- Check its extreme values
 double minVal; double maxVal;
 double max_dist = 0;
 double min_dist = 100;
 int minHessian = 630;
 Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = SIFT::create();
 vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
 Ptr<Feature2D> fd = SIFT::create();
 Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
 BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);   //BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
 vector< DMatch > matches;
 vector< DMatch > good_matches;
 vector<Point2f>imgpts1,imgpts2;
 vector<uchar> status;
while(true) 
{
    //grab and retrieve each frames of the video sequentially 
    camera0 >> frame0;
    camera1 >> frame1;
    imshow("Video0", frame0);
    imshow("Video1", frame1);

    cvtColor(frame0,frame0gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(frame1,frame1gray,CV_BGR2GRAY); 

    sbm->compute( frame0gray, frame1gray, dispbm );
    minMaxLoc( dispbm, &minVal, &maxVal );
    dispbm.convertTo( dispnorm_bm, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));

    sgbm->compute(frame0gray, frame1gray, dispsgbm);
    minMaxLoc( dispsgbm, &minVal, &maxVal );
    dispsgbm.convertTo( dispnorm_sgbm, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));
    applyColorMap(dispnorm_bm, falseColorsMap, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
    applyColorMap(dispnorm_sgbm, sfalseColorsMap, cv::COLORMAP_JET);

    f2d->detect( frame0gray, keypoints_1 );
    f2d->detect( frame1gray, keypoints_2 );

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    fd->compute( frame0gray, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
    fd->compute( frame1gray, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors with a brute force matcher

    matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );
    drawMatches(frame0gray, keypoints_1, frame1gray, keypoints_2, matches, img_matches);
    imshow("matches", img_matches);

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
    { double dist = matches[i].distance;
      if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
      if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
    } 

   for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
   {
     if( matches[i].distance <= max(4.5*min_dist, 0.02) ){
         good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
         imgpts1.push_back(keypoints_1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
         imgpts2.push_back(keypoints_2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
      }

   }

   Mat F = findFundamentalMat(imgpts1, imgpts2, cv::FM_RANSAC, 3., 0.99, status);   //FM_RANSAC
   stereoRectifyUncalibrated(imgpts1, imgpts1, F, frame0gray.size(), H1, H2);
   Mat rectified1(frame0gray.size(), frame0gray.type());
   warpPerspective(frame0gray, rectified1, H1, frame0gray.size());

   Mat rectified2(frame1gray.size(), frame1gray.type());
   warpPerspective(frame1gray, rectified2, H2, frame1gray.size());

   sgbm->compute(rectified1, rectified2, disparity);
   minMaxLoc( disparity, &minVal, &maxVal );
   disparity.convertTo( disparity1, CV_8UC1, 255/(maxVal - minVal));
   applyColorMap(disparity1, falsemap, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
   imshow("disparity_rectified_color", falsemap);
   imshow( "BM", falseColorsMap);
   imshow( "CSGBM",sfalseColorsMap);

   //wait for 40 milliseconds
    int c = cvWaitKey(40);

    //exit the loop if user press "Esc" key  (ASCII value of "Esc" is 27) 
    if(27 == char(c)) break;
}

return 0;

}
```

Now the output again isn't that good but improved from last time. However there seems to be one constant problem, that is also seen in the above image. The left side of the output image has a total black region. It shouldn't come this way right.
How to solve this problem?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

No, StereoBM doesn't do rectification, just block matching and some pre and post processing, however opencv provide functions for camera calibration and rectification check [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Also there is a ready made example for this process in opencv examples so don't have to write the code from scratch.

About the results, StereoBM is based on SAD algorithm(local stereo-matching) which is not robust, you can try [wls filter](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d14/tutorial_ximgproc_disparity_filtering.html), which could improve your results significantly.

StereoSGBM is based on SGM algorithm (actually it is a little different from the one introduced in the original paper) is semi global algorithm which consider global optimisation in disparity map generation which produce better disparity but slower.

Comment: I used the wls filter example. The results are good but the left side part of the image still seems to be the same black region. why??

Comment: This is due to the implementation, it depends on the max disparity (numDisparities) parameter (which should be chosen based on your cameras setup), you can try to decrease it but it may decrease the disparity quality as some pixels may not be matched correctly. 


I do not think there is a straight forward way to solve it, but i think you can flip(mirror) both images and then the resultant disparity will also have the same black part in the left but it will be mirrored, then you can merge both disparities.